# (PHP&JavaScript) a href add button won't work on Mozilla but works on IE and Google

Tags: php, javascript, button

I am not really certain if the add button is responsible for the problem since it is working on other browsers perfectly. I hope you could help me in someways. Thank you. By the way, here's the complete .php code.

```
<html>

<head>

<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="addOfficerStyle.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(action)
        {
            var lname=document.forms["validation"] ["lname"].value;
            var fname=document.forms["validation"] ["fname"].value;
            var mname=document.forms["validation"] ["mname"].value;
            var address=document.forms["validation"] ["address"].value;
            var contact=document.forms["validation"] ["contact"].value;

                if (lname==null || lname=="" || fname==null || fname=="" || mname==null || mname=="" || address==null || address=="" || contact==null || contact=="")
                    {
                    alert("Fill all required fields");
                    return false;
                    }
                else{
                    form = document.getElementById('userLocation');
                    form.action = action;
                    form.submit();
                    }
        }


    function numeric(e)
        {
            var unicode=e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
                if (unicode==8 || unicode==9 || (unicode >=48 && unicode <=57))
                    {
                    return true;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    return false;
                    }
        }

    function inputLimiter(e,allow)
        {
            var AllowableCharacters = '';

                if (allow == 'Letters'){AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';}

            var k = document.all?parseInt(e.keyCode): parseInt(e.which);
                if (k!=13 && k!=8 && k!=0)
                    {
                        if ((e.ctrlKey==false) && (e.altKey==false))
                            {
                                return (AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                    } 
                else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
        } 
</script>

</head>

<body onunload="opener.location=('PromoOfficer.php')">

<br><br>

<form  id="userLocation" name="validation" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <div id="tableAlign">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>ADD: Promo Officer</td></b>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
              <td>Last name:</td>    <td><input type="text" name="lname" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'Letters')" /></td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>
              <td>First name:</td>   <td><input type="text" name="fname" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'Letters')" /></td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>    
              <td>Middle name:</td>  <td><input type="text" name="mname" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'Letters')" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>Address:</td>     <td><input type="text" name="address" maxlength="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>Contact:</td>      <td><input type="text" name="contact" maxlength="11" onkeypress="return numeric(event);" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>User Type:</td>    <td><input type name = "usertype" readonly = "true" value = "Promo Officer"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<div id="addBtn">   
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript: validateForm(action);return false;"><img src="images/add.png" height="27" width="60"></a>
</div>      
<!-- PHP -->
<?
    include('global.php');


    if(isset($_REQUEST['salesID']))
        $pID = $_REQUEST['salesID'];
    else
        $pID = "";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['lname']))
        $lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
    else
        $lname = "";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['fname']))
        $fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];

    if(isset($_REQUEST['mname']))
        $mname = $_REQUEST['mname'];

    if(isset($_REQUEST['address']))
        $address = $_REQUEST['address'];

    if(isset($_REQUEST['contact']))
        $contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];

    if(isset($_REQUEST['usertype']))
        $usertype = $_REQUEST['usertype'];

            if($_POST)
                {

                    $query = "INSERT INTO promoofficerform SET ";
                    $query = $query."LastName='".$lname."', ";
                    $query = $query."FirstName='".$fname."', ";
                    $query = $query."MiddleName='".$mname."', ";
                    $query = $query."Address='".$address."', ";
                    $query = $query."Contact='".$contact."', ";
                    $query = $query."UserType='".$usertype."' ";
                    //$query = $query."WHERE PromoNameID='".$pID."'";   
                    //echo $query;
                    ExecuteQuery($query);
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        <!--
                        window.close();
                        //-->
                        </script>";
                }
?>

<!-- EndOfPHP -->

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code above is transported to jsfiddle ... see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mDnpq/

Comment: When run in FF, JS error says "opener is null", during the onload even in your body tag. Another JS error when clicking the submit button is "action is not defined"... where you used in your form here `function validateForm(action)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: validateForm(action);return false;">
```

It should be written as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="validateForm(document.forms['userLocation'].action);return false;">
```

to point your validator to the form's action.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! it works :D sorry if i replied late. again, THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Comment: @JamieBayot you forgot to accept the answer, just click on the check mark to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may not put `javascript:` into `onclick` attribute. Attributes with `on` prefix are callbacks (valid JS functions). `javascript:` is something like protocol specification. So you may use `javascript:` only in `href` attribute. Something like:

```
<a href="javascript: alert(123)">test</a>
```

To fix your problem just remove `javascript:` from `onlick`.

```
<div id="addBtn">   
        <a href="#" onclick="validateForm(action);return false;"><img src="images/add.png" height="27" width="60"></a>
</div>
```