# JavaScript Property vs Label?

Tags: javascript

If I write in Javascript :

```
var o= { aaa :s };
```

How does he know to distiguish between

1) label named `aaa`

[image]

2) property named `aaa` ( IMHO  , properties *can* be used without `"`)

Comment: Because you may use labels only with loops

Comment: @Serjio — That isn't true. It only makes *sense* to do that, but labels are allowed in lots of places. Hence the headdesking insanity of `onclick="javascript:foo()"`.

Comment: Your code does not work in all browsers. Because `javascript:` is something like protocol notation not a label

Comment: @Serjio — No, it isn't. It is nothing like a protocol notation except when it appears in a URI. The onclick attribute does not take a URI. People use it because they learned how to write inline JS with href attributes and it became a cargo cult practise.

Comment: @Quentin it's sutiable to use labels only with loops because javascript does not have `goto` construction. You may go to the label only with `continue` or `break` operators inside loops. There are no other cases

Comment: @Serjio — That's why it only makes sense to use it with loops. The language allows them in lots of places.

Comment: @Quentin Yes you can but this construction does not work in all browsers. There was a question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500435/phpjavascript-a-href-add-button-wont-work-on-mozilla-but-works-on-ie-and-goo/11500661

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put simply:

- A property (like that) can appear only in object literals.
- A label cannot appear inside an object literal.

… and the JavaScript parser knows what it is parsing at any given point in the code.

It gets a little more complex when you have (for example) a function as the value of a property, but it basically comes down to parse modes. At that point the stack of things being parsed would have a function on top and the object literal below it. The object literal parsing wouldn't become "active" again until the function was finished.

A detailed example of how to parse HTML is provided in the [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#parsing). The principles are basically the same for JavaScript.

Comment: ok. So is `{blah: alert(123)}` an object notation or just a block with label?=)

Comment: @Serjio — Depends on the context. `{` means "Start an object literal" in some places and "Start a block" in others. It works in the same way as deciding if something is a label or a property.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis yes but why? How does the parser know this?

Comment: As I understand it (caveat: I have been known to be wrong before), it is basically as Quentin says - the parser is aware of the context from the moment it starts parsing the code, so when it encounters a function it knows that a new block is defined for the function body, which goes back to previous parsing mode after the function body definition finishes.

Comment: @Quentin If i want to return object `return { "summary": s, "total": total };` Must I use `"` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir — There is no case when the (JS) context an object literal appears in will make quotes mandatory.

Comment: I've added a link to the HTML 5 specification's description of how to parse that language. It serves as an example of how parsers can work.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis The question is how does parser know that `{blah: alert(123)}` is an object and not a block with declared label inside

Comment: Surely it's a block if it's preceded with `function()`,`for(...)`,`if(...)`,`while(...)` etc? The parser doesn't work out whether `blah` is a property key or a label until it knows whether the containing parens specify a block or an object literal.

Comment: @Quentin Where is a connection between JavaScript parser and HTML parser?

Comment: @ChrisFrancis You may define blocks without `function, for, if, while, etc.` using curly braces `{}`. The only difference is that block does not have own context (like in C++ for example or Java). So I have asked how does the parser know that this construction is not a block without context?

Comment: @Serjio — They are both parsers that parse a formal language where the same symbol means different things in different contexts.

Comment: @Serjio — There is *always* context. If that was the whole script, then it would be a block because `{` in the state the parser starts in `{` means "start a block". Read the EMCAScript grammer if you want the precise details of the modes.

Comment: @Quentin i know. I mean that block `{}` does not create own context. It uses parent context.

Comment: @Serjio — No. The parent context determines if `{` is an object literal start or a block start. Being in a block does create its own context. (It doesn't create a new *scope* since JS has function based scope, not block based scope, but scope is not context).